# Enable wireless, no X, on nixos

Tags: nixos

What is the configuration I would use to enable my wireless adapter WITHOUT having any X Server/Desktop installed.  The install is simply a terminal install.  Also I want to specify a static IP address for the machine.  If someone could share the nixos configuration to achieve that, it would be appreciated.

Comment: try reading [this](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-wireless) for wireless and [this](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-ipv4) for IP. Sorry for not writing a full answer. I don't have any wireless notebook to try right now.

Comment: Did you try enabling `networking.networkmanager.enable` and using the
`nmtui` client?

Answer (score 3):

This code will do it:

```
  networking = {
    interfaces.wlp1s0.ip4 = [ { address = "192.168.0.150"; prefixLength = 24; } ];
    defaultGateway = "192.168.0.1";
    nameservers = [ "8.8.8.8" ];

    wireless = {
      enable = true;
      interfaces = ["wlp1s0"];
      userControlled.enable = true;
      userControlled.group = "wheel";
      networks = {
        "1529-upstairs-2.4" = {
          psk = "abc7654321";
        };
      };
    };

    hostName = "delldesk"; 
  };

 environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
   dhcpcd wpa_supplicant
 ];
```

my wireless device is: `wlp1s0`.

I have a network called: `1529-upstairs-2.4`

The password to that WIFI is: `abc7654321`